# "this" inside function call on another function

Tags: javascript

```
    Function.prototype.bind = function (obj) {
      const self = this;
      console.log(this);
      return () => {
        return this.apply(obj, arguments);
      };
    }

    MyObj1 = function () {
      this.myName = 'myObj1';
    }

    MyObj1.prototype.who = function () {
      console.log(this.myName);
    }

    myObj2 = {
      myName: 'myObj2'
    }

    myObj1 = new MyObj1();
    myObj1.who();

    who2 = myObj1.who.bind(myObj2);
    who2();
```

produced the following output:

```
myObj1

ƒ () {
      console.log(this.myName);
}

myObj2
```

is *who2 = myObj1.who.bind(myObj2);* treat **.who** as an object and bind **this** to it?
looks like but still confusing to me

Comment: Yes. `.bind` is called on `myObj1.who` so it's the value of `this` === `MyObj1.prototype.who`. It's clearly not the most obvious part of JS.

Comment: Yes, `myObj1.who` is a function object on which the method is called.